# Strange issue cannot add integer values

Tags: laravel, php-7.1

I have this strange issue where i am using laravel 5.5 on php 7.1 i am returning 2 values to the blade from the controller as a direct query from the db

```
{{$news[0]->new_members_sale ?? 0+ $renewsb[0]->renew_members_sale ?? 0 }}
```

I am direct in my blade adding to values .

I have checked the 2 values `$news[0]->new_members_sale`  and  `$renewsb[0]->renew_members_sale` they contain the values.

so i can say I have value `$a=5.00`  and value `$b=10.00`

when I add `{{$a+$b}}`  the sum is only `5.00` and not `15.00` like its supposed to be .

I have tried to type cast the values eg `$c=(int)$a+ (int)$b;` and add but still doesn't give correct sum.

```
{{$news[0]->new_members_sale ?? 0 + $renewsb[0]->renew_members_sale ?? 0 }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the error , it was apparently in the mysql query if you use Format on Format (coalesce(SUM(amount),0),2) it causes the value to change from  1300.00  to  1,300.00   so   in my blade i could not at  1,300.00 +50.00  it gave a non well formed numeric value error because of the comma.